# How do I put spaces between these buttons on my vertical navigation bar?

Tags: html, css, navbar, nav

Just what the title says. Iwant there to be spaces in between the four buttons in the vertical navigation bar. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/u55M5/)

HTML

```
<div id="classesnav">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Buttercream Skills</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Flower and Cake Design</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Gum Paste and Fondant</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Advanced Gum Paste Flowers</a></li>
</ul>
</div><!--end of classesnav-->
```

CSS

```
#classesnav {   
position:absolute;
}

#classesnav ul {
list-style:none;
display:block;  
}

#classesnav ul li {
padding:10px 3px 10px 3px;
background-color:#FEC7FD;
display:block;
border-radius:10px; 
}

#classesnav ul li a {
display:block;  
text-decoration:none;
color:#000000;
}
```

Comment: You have a typo.. `display:inline:block;` should be `display:inline-block;`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jats_ptl/u55M5/3/ is this you are looking for.

Comment: Oh, thanks. That makes the bar horizontal though unfortunately. I want the buttons to stay vertical but have spaces between them.

Comment: Remove the inline block for vertical buttons. `margin-bottom` for spacing between.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe using `margin-bottom`:

```
#classesnav ul li {
    padding:10px 3px 10px 3px;
    background-color:#FEC7FD;
    display:inline:block;
    border-radius:10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;    
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u55M5/4/)